# How do I code an imbalanced dichotomous predictor variable and still have the intercept represent the overall mean?

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data

I am running a mixed effects logistic regression. I have one dichotomous predictor variable (participant gender). However, there are far more females than males in the study. I would like my intercept to tell me if participants are overall more likely to succeed, even after taking participant gender into account.

My understanding is that if I used dummy coding, the intercept would simply be the mean of the reference group, which wouldn't serve my purpose. Also, if I used effects coding, the intercept would not be the grand mean because of the imbalance between males and females in the study.

Is there a way to code gender that would still allow the intercept to represent the overall success rate, and allow me to test whether that success rate is significantly different than chance after accounting for participant gender?

Edit: As a bonus...it seems like in this case the level that I choose as the reference category matters when random slopes variables are in the model. Is that only the case with imbalanced levels of a factor?

Comment: Offset the overall mean (the log odds of the mean if you're in logistic regression land), and then estimate a model without an intercept?  I'm sure there is a fancy way to accomplish the same thing, but that would get you there with little effort.

Comment: Can you tell me a bit more about this approach? I would offset the overall mean by adding/subtracting some constant from each observation? What would the intercept then represent?